# NSTimer Category + Blocks implementation to replace selector

Tags: ios, nstimer, categories, objective-c-blocks

I am quite new to blocks and objective-c, and i am trying to write my first category using both. My idea is to create a category on NSTimer that will receive a block as a parameter and this block will be used in the selector call. Right now I have this.

```
// NSTimer+Additions.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef void (^VoidBlock)();

@interface NSTimer (NSTimer_Additions)


+ (NSTimer *)scheduleTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)theSeconds repeats:(BOOL)repeats actions:(VoidBlock)actions;
@end

#import "NSTimer+Additions.h"

static VoidBlock _voidBlock;

@interface NSTimer (AdditionsPrivate) // Private stuff
- (void)theBlock;
@end


@implementation NSTimer (NSTimer_Additions)


+ (NSTimer *)scheduleTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)theSeconds repeats:(BOOL)repeats actions:(VoidBlock)actions {

    [_voidBlock release];
    _voidBlock = [actions copy];

    NSTimer* timer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:[NSDate date] 
                                          interval:theSeconds
                                            target:self 
                                          selector:@selector(theBlock) 
                                          userInfo:nil 
                                           repeats:repeats];
    [timer fire];

    return [timer autorelease];
}


- (void)theBlock {
    _voidBlock();
}

@end
```

Gist for the code: https://gist.github.com/1065235

Everything compiles fine but i have the following error:

2011-07-05 14:35:47.068 TesteTimer[37716:903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSTimer theBlock]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x7fff70bb0a18'

How can I make this category work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your major flaw besides the wrong target is your use of a static variable. You won't be able to support beyond a single timer.

#### Using block as argument to the invoked method.

```
@interface NSTimer (AdditionsPrivate) // Private stuff
- (void)theBlock:(VoidBlock)voidBlock;
@end


@implementation NSTimer (NSTimer_Additions)

+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)theSeconds repeats:(BOOL)repeats actions:(VoidBlock)actions {
    NSInvocation * invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[self instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:@selector(theBlock:)]];
    NSTimer * timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:theSeconds
                                                   invocation:invocation
                                                      repeats:repeats];
    [invocation setTarget:timer];
    [invocation setSelector:@selector(theBlock:)];
    
    Block_copy(actions);
    [invocation setArgument:&actions atIndex:2];
    Block_release(actions);

    return timer;
}


- (void)theBlock:(VoidBlock)voidBlock {
    voidBlock();
}

@end
```

The problem with using associative references was the leak as there was no good point to release the block.

---

#### Earlier Approach using associative references

You can use [`associative references`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-DontLinkElementID_3) to attach the block to that particular instance of `NSTimer`.

```
@implementation NSTimer (NSTimer_Additions)

+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)theSeconds repeats:(BOOL)repeats actions:(VoidBlock)actions {
    NSInvocation * invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[self instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:@selector(theBlock)]];
    NSTimer * timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:theSeconds
                                                   invocation:invocation
                                                      repeats:repeats];
    [invocation setTarget:timer];
    [invocation setSelector:@selector(theBlock)];

    objc_setAssociatedObject(timer, @"Block", actions, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY);
    
    return timer;
}


- (void)theBlock {
    VoidBlock _voidBlock = (VoidBlock)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @"Block");
    _voidBlock();
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i am still trying to understand how the nsinvocation and the associative references work, copy/pasting the source doesn't solved what I need to do, but I think it is the way to go.

Comment: Didn't know 'associative references', thank you so much!! worked very well

Comment: Block copying should always be done as `actions = Block_copy(actions);` or `actions = [actions copy];` because `copy` does not always return the same object. Also, you need to do `[invocation retainArguments];` otherwise it won't be retained by the invocation.

Answer (score 2):

What about leveraging userInfo to carry your block? (this is done with ARC)

```
void (^callback)(void) = ^{
    NSLog(@"do stuff");
}

NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(handleTimeout:) userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[callback copy] forKey:@"block"] repeats:NO];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

And then add the static selector of:

```
+ (void)handleTimeout:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    void (^callback)(void) = [timer.userInfo objectForKey:@"block"];
    callback();

    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
NSTimer* timer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:[NSDate date] 
                                          interval:theSeconds
                                            target:timer
                                          selector:@selector(theBlock) 
                                          userInfo:nil 
                                           repeats:repeats];
```

The problem is that you're setting the target of the new `NSTimer` instance to be `self`. However, in the context of `+ scheduleTimerWithTimeInterval:repeats:actions:` (notice the `+`), `self` is `NSTimer`, and not (as you probably thought) your newly-created `NSTimer` instance.

As you can see from the error message, your app is crashing because `NSTimer` doesn't respond to the class method `+ theBlock`, which is of course correct since you only defined  the instance method `- theBlock`.

Comment: the warning is gone but it doesn't call my block. thanks for the fast answer.