# NSTimer starts after the method which is called after it finishes

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, nstimer

Im using an NSTimer to update a UIProgressView so that every second the progess is increased by 0.1.

```
-(void)updateBar{
     NSLog(@"Increase by 0.1");
     pbar.progress=pbar.progress+0.1;
 }

 -(void)foo{
    NSLog("START Foo");
    //Does some stuff that takes about 10sec
    NSLog("FINISH Foo");
 }

 -(void) viewDidLoad{
     pbar = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-280, 500, 730, 90)];
     pbar.progressViewStyle = UIProgressViewStyleDefault;
     pbar.progressTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:68.0/255 green:186.0/255 blue:41.0/255 alpha:1.0];
     pbar.progress = 0.0;
     pbar.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(90 * M_PI / 180.0);
     [self.view addSubview:pbar];

     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateBar) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];

     [self foo];
 }
```

So ideally the UIProgressView's progress increases during the time the foo method is running. However, the timer starts after the foo method finishes so my console ends up looking like this...

```
START Foo
FINISH Foo
Increase by 0.1
Increase by 0.1
Increase by 0.1
And so on ....
```

Any idea why this might happen? And more importantly how do I get it to do what I want and get the timer to start running before foo is called.

Comment: You could just call `-updateBar` at the start of `-foo`

Answer (score 0):

The particular method you're calling, "`scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`", runs the timer on the *current* run loop, which explains why "foo" does it's thing before the timer fires.

If you want to run things on a separate (background) thread, why not create & detach a thread ([or blocks, here's a related question that might help you out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586662/nstimer-category-blocks-implementation-to-replace-selector)) and then run that same call on the separate thread.  Of course, if you're doing anything related to UI, you must do the actual UI updating on the main thread.  So while the timer runs on a separate thread, do the actual UI stuff on the main thread (via something like "`performSelectorOnMainThread:`").

Comment: Ok cool thanks, so I ended up using `performSelectorInBackground:` and sort of got it doing what I want, however I used `performSelectorOnMainThread:` to call `updateBar` because I want it to change the UI and that doesn't work because the UI changes wait until the foo is done before they appear.

Answer (score 0):

The `- (void) updateBar` method is deferred on the run loop, while the `- (void) foo` is executed immediately.

As you have implemented the code, you are missing a reference (specifically an instance variable) to the `NSTimer` that you will use to end the timer.

You would use the variable at the end of the `- (void) foo` method to stop the timer.